# Roles and permissions , store permission sets in role table or in multiple rolepermission records?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, database-design

Which database design would be most efficient for an SaaS product, and why?

---

Design1: three tables (standard way to design your role permission tables)

```
ROLE
Id
Name
Description 

PERMISSION 
Id
Name

ROLEPERMISSION
Id
RoleId
PermissionId
```

---

Design2: two tables

```
ROLE
Id
Name
Description 
PermissionSetData


PERMISSION 
Id
Name
```

Where role.permissionsetdata column contains a CVS of permissionsets stored in the role record. (Save database storage space, may help with performance?)

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1 is the only appropriate design.

- Saving database storage space is nearly always a moot point here I think. When you can buy **TERA** bytes of space at a reasonable price, why would you try saving a few **kilo** bytes? (the space needed for each solution would be approximately the same).
- The multi-value column in the second design doesn't follow [proper database design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).
- From a practical point of view, retrieving data in a muli-value column is massively more complex and expensive than in a properly designed db. For instance, you can't index a CSV column properly, you can't join easily.